# How date a Fuji GW690 III by the serial number?

Tags: fujifilm, rangefinder

In *[Photo Thinking: Fuji GSW690III Professional – The Texas Leica](https://www.photothinking.com/29161011fuji-gsw690iii-professional-the-texas-leica/)*, the author claims to date the camera by serial number, but doesn't explain how to do so.

> My camera, based on serial number, does indicate it is a mid-nineties model...

Is there a way to date the Fuji GW690 III by serial number? If so, how?

Comment: I suspect the blog author was just playing the odds. You can post a comment on the blog to ask for further information if you believe otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Camerapedia: Fujica GW690](https://camerapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Fujica_GW690), the GW690 III was released in February 1992. There is a [photo.net post](https://www.photo.net/discuss/threads/fuji-gsw690iii-discontinued.10673/) from Nov 2001 that describes a FujiFilm representative stating that the camera had been discontinued.

If the camera was discontinued prior to 2000, *all* GW690 III cameras, regardless of serial number, would have been manufactured in the "mid-nineties". There would still be a greater than 80% chance that any given camera was made in the "mid-nineties" if production had continued into 2000-2001.

As you've [noted](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/112561/how-date-a-fuji-gw690-iii-by-the-serial-number/112571?noredirect=1#comment215969_112571), knowing the range of values can be helpful, assuming they are assigned sequentially, starting with 1. The [blog](https://www.photothinking.com/29161011fuji-gsw690iii-professional-the-texas-leica/) author probably thought that the serial number didn't look too high and guessed that it was *probably* made in the 1990s since he states:

> It is not easily clear in any searches I have performed when Fuji decided to discontinue these cameras, but I would hazard a guess at the early 2000s.

Comment: by reading serial on camera on sell in ebay many have number around 5000000 and the biggest I have found was more than 8000000. This could give a very rough indication.